# php call to getnewaddress through rpc gives isValid false address

Tags: bitcoind, php

I am using easybitcoin.php to make rpc calls to bitcoind running on my server.

When I call `$result = $bitcoin->getnewaddress();` from the php code, I get back an address, however when I run that address through:

```
$result = $bitcoin->validateaddress('mwFXW37HgXTHwtigRyLZDCAohgabswktoF1');
```

The result is always `isValid => false`

If I create this from command line using `bitcoin-cli getnewaddress`, then `validateaddress` returns a json dump, as expected.

Why is the behavior different for both cases?

I am on -regtest and not mainnet.

My worry is that the `getnewaddress` through rpc is not creating a valid account somehow.

FYI, my wallet is encrypted with a passphrase.